# Recursive call on the java memory leaks

Tags: java

```
public class TailRecursionTest2 {   
    public static void main(String[] args) {   
        TailRecursionTest2 t = new TailRecursionTest2();   
        t.a(0);   
    }   
    public void a(int j) {   
        System.out.println(j);   
        j++;   
        if (j == 10000)   
            return;   
        List list = new Array List<Integer>(100000);   
} 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
         at java.util.ArrayList. <init> (Unknown Source)
         at TailRecursionTest2.a (TailRecursionTest2.java: 17)
         at TailRecursionTest2.a (TailRecursionTest2.java: 20)
         at TailRecursionTest2.a (TailRecursionTest2.java: 20)
         at TailRecursionTest2.a (TailRecursionTest2.java: 20)
         at TailRecursionTest2.a (TailRecursionTest2.java: 20)
```

Comment: Bad editing, no question. Your question will be closed very fast.

Comment: Please add some sample code, or it's impossible to answer this.

Comment: Answering this will be like shooting in dark.

Comment: Java doesn't support tail recursion optimisation.  You should consider using a loop instead, esp if you have tail recursion.

Comment: As far as I can tell there's no recursion in the sample code (and there's a missing bracket). You should at least make sure that the sample code compiles and produces the result you're asking about.

Comment: For tips regarding code samples, see [sscce.org](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue as you can guess is that you got a memory leek because of the heap is full. You could fix it by increasing the Java heap space but the issue is probably related to your code which may not deallocate the variables properly or your recursive function does not have an "exit point" (check the iteration condition)

Answer (score 1):

Without being able to see your code, I can suggest that you are most probably recursing too deep.

Check whether your termination conditions for your recursion are sane, and that your start conditions are sane.

Basically you are pushing so much stuff onto the Heap that the JVM is giving up and going to paint seagulls in Bali.

Comment: speculation but +1 because can potentially provide guidance to other.

Comment: What if the application itself needs bigger stack than default ?

Comment: The name of the application (TailRecursionTest) leads me to believe that this isn't the case, and that it is rather a case that the OP doesn't have any termination conditions set up.

Comment: But I guess in that case the error would be StackOverflowError !

Comment: well, only if the overflow is being caused by method calls or instance variables.  In this case it would seem to be overallocation of objects, hence the exhausting of heap space.  Whichever it is, it is almost certainly because the program is recursing out of control.

Answer (score -1):

Always make the arraylist and other references used in your program as null in finally block.
Saves a lot of headache :)

-Lav

Comment: -1 Explicitly nulling objects is considered a bad practice. There are rarely occasions you have to to this.